# Is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{8}$ a free abelian group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Is $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{8}$ a free abelian group?

Clearly this group has a torsion component and a torsion-free component. The torsion-free component is a free abelian group with basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$, but what about the torsion component?

If it is a free abelian group, what would its basis be?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_abelian_group#Torsion_and_divisibility), all free abelian groups are torsion-free, but $\operatorname{ord} (0, 0, 0, 1) = 8 < +\infty$.

Comment: So is the rank of the group 2 or 4? Since this group has 4 generators but contains a free abelian subgroup with rank 2?

Comment: It is usually defined, at least for finitely generated abelian groups, that *the rank* of an abelian group is the rank of its free direct summand, so yes: here the rank would indeed be two.

Comment: @W.Scott: In other words rank of an abelian group $G$ is the dimension of the $\mathbb Q$ vector space $G \otimes \mathbb {Q}$. So rank is $2$.

Answer (score 0):

(1) *$\mathbb{Z}_4$ is not free abelian group*: since for any subset $S$ of this group which do not contains $0$, take any map from $S$ to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ which sends some element $s\in S$ to a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_3$; it can not be extended to a homomorphism.

(2) Subgroup of a free abelian group should be free abelian.